# How to change each other textbox when changing value (MVVM)

Tags: c#, mvvm

How can I change my textboxes depending on the others?

Before I had an Button with Icommand and now the textboxes should change when another textbox is changing

```
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text ="{Binding Decimal, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Text ="{Binding Dual, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Text ="{Binding Hexa, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Text ="{Binding Octa, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"/>
```

So in general I want to convert the numbers in the other system, no matter in which textbox the user is writing, how can I do this?

A property behind looks like this:

```
    public string Decimal
    {
        get { return Number.Decimal; }
        set
        {
            if (Number.Decimal != value)
            {
                Number.Decimal = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Decimal");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does Number Class implement inotifypropertychanged?

Comment: yes, I am using a library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the `Number` is your model - it stores the number inside, and properly manages the number conversions.

The easiest solution would be to just call for an update of each relevant property when one of them is touched in the ViewModel.

```
private void NumbersChanged()
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Decimal));
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Dual));
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Hexa));
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Octa));
}

public string Decimal
{
    get { return Number.Decimal; }
    set
    {
        if (Number.Decimal != value)
        {
            Number.Decimal = value;
            NumbersChanged();
        }
    }
}

public string Hexa
{
    get { return Number.Hexa; }
    set
    {
        if (Number.Hexa != value)
        {
            Number.Hexa = value;
            NumbersChanged();
        }
    }
}
//etc...
```